# Aligning Contents of Span

Tags: html, css

I have a Table with content and i cannot figure out how to align the content of the spans inside the table.

[HERE IS THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LxD9N/5/)

Here is have pasted 2 images. 1st image is actual result and second is desired result.I think that explains it all...

[image]
[image]

CODE:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px;">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: #d3d3d3;">
            <td colspan="2" style="padding: 5px; font-weight: bold;">Order Details</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px; font-weight: bold; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: #d3d3d3; width: 60%;">Order ID: <span style="font-weight: normal;text-align">#YCKY141</span>

            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Email: <span style="font-weight: normal;">wyz@ymca.com</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 5px; font-weight: bold; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: #d3d3d3; width: 60%;">Date: <span style="font-weight: normal;">28/03/2014</span>

            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 20px; font-weight: bold;">Telephone: <span style="font-weight: normal;">XXX-XXX-XXXX</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 5px; font-weight: bold; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: #d3d3d3; width: 60%;">Payment Method: <span style="font-weight: normal;">On Invoice</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 5px; font-weight: bold; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: #d3d3d3; width: 60%;">Shipping Method: <span style="font-weight: normal;">Royal Mail</span>

            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 20px;"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: why are you using inline styles? do yourself a favor and write some css

Comment: I cannot. THis is part of an email template. I cannot include css files...

Comment: nice of you to mention that before @kittMedia spend some time creating a nice solution for you!

Comment: have a look at my answer. hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little bit changes you have to apply to your table.

have a look at <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LxD9N/10/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px;">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: #d3d3d3;">
            <td colspan="2" style="padding: 5px; font-weight: bold;">Order Details</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: #d3d3d3; border-width:1px">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px; font-weight: bold; ; width: 60%;">Order ID: 

                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 20px;"><span style="font-weight: normal; text-align">#YCKY141</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 5px; font-weight: bold; width: 60%;">Date: 

                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 20px;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">28/03/2014</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 5px; font-weight: bold; width: 60%;">payment Method: 

                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 20px;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">OnInvoice</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 5px; font-weight: bold; width: 60%;">Shipping Method: 

                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 20px;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">Royal Mail</span></td>
                    </tr>


                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span style="font-weight: normal;">wyz@ymca.com</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Telephone: 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span style="font-weight: normal;">XXX-XXX-XXXX</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a proper table layout:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="headline">Order Details</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="first">Order ID:</td>
            <td class="second">#YCKY141</td>
            <td class="third"></td>
            <td class="fourth"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="first">Date:</td>
            <td class="second">2014-03-28</td>
            <td class="third">Email</td>
            <td class="fourth">wyz@ymca.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}

table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.headline {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
}

.first,
.third {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 5px;
    width: 20%;
}

.second,
.fourth {
    width: 30%;
}

.third {
    border-left: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kZ7Hj/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each key (Order Id, Date, etc.) in a `span` with `display:inline-block` and a width.

Example:

```
<span style="display:inline-block;width:40%;">Order Id</span>
```

<del>**Edit:** Be sure to remove the inline styles when you're done experimenting. It'll make maintenance and debugging a lot easier.</del> Just saw your comment about this being for an email template. I haven't looked at css support in email clients in some time and `display:inline-block` might not be supported.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is what you want but I applied :

```
<div style="width:200px; display:inline-block;">..</div>
```

on labels and it seems to be aligned just fine.

Here you can find an example: http://jsfiddle.net/LxD9N/12/

Answer (score -1):

Replace the `<span>` element with an extra `<td>` element and align it.